# Decrypting Cookie in Rails 5.1.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the cookie store as the session store in my Rails application (5.1.7).

I'm seeing a weird bug in my staging environment due to some marshalling error:

TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read) format version 4.8 required; XX.XX given

I've traced down this error to be a Marshalling error caused by an unability to load the decyphered cookie.

Is there any way in which I can decypher a staging cookie locally, if I have the secret_key_base?

Comment: Can't see how the error stack relates to my question, as my question was if there is any way in which I can decrypt a cookie given the secret_key_base.

The rest of the information was just context.

Thanks for reaching out though.

Comment: We are going to need some additional context as to where in your code this error is happening, what is currently happening, and what you expect to happen. As of right now the question is unclear, since you are saying the issue is in stage but you want to "decypher" locally. Also have you confirmed that the versions of all gems are the same across environments?

Comment: The same versions of gems are used between all environments.

My question is, given the secret key used in the staging environment, is there any way in which I can decypher a cookie ORIGINATING from the staging environment, in my local environment.

The question can also be put as 'is there a hardcoded salt used for Rails' default encryption mechanism or is it dynamically generated on a per-worker basis?'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120560/decrypting-rails-5-session-manually-when-secret-key-base-is-nil